# Adding depth to a sprite in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i have a 2d object, something like a square grid. I would like to add some depth to it so it looks like its going off into the distance so the top left and right points of the square should get closer together, something like looking down a long road. I currently have the square make on a 2d surface and it looks fine i was just wondering if theres a method in Cocos2d that will rotate the square and give that effect. I've tried using

```
CCFiniteTimeAction* action = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:7 key:@"scaleY" from:.5 to:1.2];
    [self runAction:action];
```

but that only seems to decrease the length and width of the square and not actually adds any depth to it. I found CCTransitionFlipY which seems like it would give a desired effect but it looks like that is only for Scenes. Any help into this would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice solution here. I used CCOrbitCamera to get the desired effect!